# PHP Session Variables lifetime

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

I tried to program a simple disclaimer plugin for wordpress, which every time a new user access my site shows a disclaimer popup. I've used php session variables but they don't get deleted in chrome when a user restart his browser. I really don't know why it isn't working?

```
add_filter('init','check_disclaimer');

function check_disclaimer()
{
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
    {
        session_set_cookie_params(0);
        session_start();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['disclaimer-accepted']))
    {
        $_SESSION['disclaimer']=1;
    }

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {

        if (!isset($_SESSION['disclaimer']))
        {

            include('includes/overlay.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you get an error? Do you have WP_DEBUG enabled?

Comment: Any specific browser? Anything specific with that browser installation?

Comment: It's a normal google chrome installation, it works in firefox and internet explorer

Comment: It cant be a Chrome specific issue, `$_SESSION` variables are stored on the server. The browser remembers your session because of a `$_COOKIE`. Where is your code for the cookies?